Best test to evaluate vote significance
What is the best test to evaluate a vote's significance and why?
This article evaluates the US Supreme Court voting system and the voting system of the congress and says both fail significance tests https://medium.com/@akashkamble8488/the-usa-supreme-court-and-congress-fail-basic-statistical-significance-tests-b49f74f1ba41
The methods used in the article are the A/B, Welch's test and binary test.
Details: To measure a vote's significance, as to how likely that the vote is not by chance, there are many tests that can be used to give good approximations to a Null test without all its complications. For example: A Random vote R has p of R = 1/2 and q of R = 1/2 and u = 0. A regular vote V has p and q, and then Welch's test was used to measure the distance between the means of R and V divided by the combined standard deviation of R and V. If the results are 2 or greater (z >= 2 for 95% Confidence Level), then the article shows when the vote V (for a US Supreme Standard or Congress) passes the significance test or fails.
Example: The standard of the US Supreme Court of accepting a 5 to 4 for a vote is shown to fail the significance test, the standard for accepting a vote needs to be 8-1 or 9-0 depending on needed Confidence Level of 95% or 99.7%
The article notes that when doing the computation of a vote's mean and SD, a "yes" vote has a value 1 and a "no" vote has a value of -1 (not 0), and in this case, SD=sqrt(4pq) NOT sqrt(pq).
I hope that this clarifies the question more.

The linked article strikes me as ridiculous and making a fundamental error. Votes in the House, Senate, and SCOTUS (and similar bodies in other countries) are not random samples of any population: You have the whole population. There is no inference to be done. Also "voting systems" do not pass or fail significance tests. And, finally, I think the article confuses two meanings of "fail" a test in English.

Agree with @PeterFlom. Many members of these bodies vote along party lines, and if there are slim majorities, results will be around 50/50, which at the same time means they will not be statistically significant (in the sense of the cited article), and also obviously nonrandom (which means that the 50% randomness null hypothesis that is tested there doesn't make sense). Also, the Supreme Court has nine members, a very small number making it hard to see anything that rejects the 50% randomness null hypothesis (which is nonsensical here anyway).

Could you elaborate on what you mean by the "significance" of a vote?

What is the null hypothesis?

Thanks for closing the question. I'm hoping the linked article is just someone's elaborate spoof on statistics.

details added. " Thanks for closing the question. I'm hoping the linked article is just someone's elaborate spoof on statistics."  What?

Not to put too fine a point on it, but the thesis of the referenced post, "statistical significance helps determine whether a voting result is meaningful or could have arisen by chance," reflects a thoroughgoing ignorance of both statistics and voting.  Please do not pay any attention to that post.  Consider researching the concepts of statistical testing with a good textbook or even by exploring our site.  We have many threads about voting.  cc @Graham

" Please do not pay any attention to that post". Why are some people afraid of other people knowing what pure statistics is saying about the Supreme Court and Congress? If these judges or congressmen were judging a court criminal case, would this jury composed of them not be required to be unanimous? a unanimous requirement for decisions implies these institutions cannot interfere in public life as much. Is this your objection? This post is a statistical question. If you compute the number of the judges or congressmen for their vote to have significance, please share with us.

Can someone compute the number of judges, or senators, for their vote to have significance (at  p-value of 0.05, and 0.01) and share the results with us here.
